# exception when loading the properties from the db.properties file

Tags: java, mysql

the exception message is: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver". I checked the credentials and they are correct the database is also running, I don't know where else to look since it is in github and my team can run it with no problems it's just me that can't insert into the database

```
Severe:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.nbcc.dataaccess.DAL.propertiesSetUp(DAL.java:182)
at com.nbcc.dataaccess.DAL.executeNonQuery(DAL.java:43)
at com.nbcc.wmad.repository.TaskRepository.insertTask(TaskRepository.java:52)
at com.nbcc.wmad.business.TaskService.createTask(TaskService.java:38)
at project.controllers.TasksController.doPost(TasksController.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you added the mysqlconnector jar file in your libraries?

Comment: Yes I just checked and it is there

Comment: What is the version of MySQL connector you are using?

Comment: it is the 8.0.12 but it has been working before

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace, so we could have a better idea what’s is going on

Comment: I added the exception info because it doesn't break the app and doesn't show it on the jsp project

Comment: An exception’s message by itself is useless.  Many exceptions have a null or very short message!  Use `printStackTrace()` and copy the entire stack trace into your question, including any “Caused by:” sections.  Please copy it as text, not as an image.

Comment: I edited and put what printStackTrace() printed in the glasfish console

Comment: @Kevin do see my answer let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the error is coming as a result of not being able to find the `mysqlconnector.jar` file.

**If you are using a Git repo, make sure the jars make it into the WEB-INF/lib INSIDE the git repo and not just in the project WEB-INF/lib**

You can also try to make your JDBC jar available either in WEB-INF/lib, for example

- Add the jar file to your WEB-INF/lib folder.
- Right-click your project in Eclipse, and go to "Build Path > Configure Build Path"
- Add the "Web App Libraries" library

This will ensure all WEB-INF/lib jars are included on the classpath.